# Github pages loads Hugo theme with missing CSS and images

Tags: git, github, github-pages, github-actions

I am using [this Hugo theme](https://themes.gohugo.io/themes/hugo-theme-bootstrap/) on [my Github pages](https://github.com/MixedPebble/myblog) and while the page does load, the images, CSS, and redirection does not. I've followed the instructions on the theme's repo with the official [gohugo instruction](https://gohugo.io/hosting-and-deployment/hosting-on-github/) which boils down to this:

```
hugo new site myblog
cd myblog
git init
git submodule add https://github.com/razonyang/hugo-theme-bootstrap themes/hugo-theme-bootstrap
cp -a themes/hugo-theme-bootstrap/exampleSite/* .

mkdir -p .github/workflows/gh-pages.yml
```

I then copied the content from the Gohugo instructions to the gh-pages.yml. switching the two uses of the "main" branch to "master". After pushing everything to the new repo, I went into settings and set the github pages source branch to gh-pages.

My assumption is that the github actions step is missing something but I'm not sure what since it looks like the files are present in the gh-pages branch.

[image: Broken page]

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and used the [`actions/checkout`](https://github.com/actions/checkout) action to pull the code from the repo. If you use a submodule the action has a flag to also checkout the submodule. This would be an example:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
        - name: Install hugo
          run: sudo apt install hugo

        - name: Checkout repository
          uses: actions/checkout@v3
          with:
            submodules: 'true'

        - name: Build
          run: hugo
```

My blog has a full example of building a Hugo website and deploying to an S3 bucket.

https://github.com/caiocsgomes/caiogomes.me